# Identify patterns within list of words with pattern threshold

Tags: python, arrays, loops, masking

Working on a pattern recognition function in Python that suppose to return an array of patterns with a counter

Let's imagine a list of strings:

```
m = ['ABA','ABB', 'ABC','BCA','BCB','BCC','ABBC', 'ABBA', 'ABBC']
```

at the high-level, what I would like to get back is:

```
Pattern | Count
----------------
   AB   |   6
  ABB   |   4
   BC   |   3
----------------
```

The problem: all I know that patterns begin with 2 characters and are leading characters for each string value (i.e. XXZZZ, XXXZZZ (where XX is a pattern that I'm looking for)). I would like to be able to parametrize minimal length of a pattern as a function's input to optimize the run time.

PS. each item in the list is a single word already.

my problem is that I need to iterate for each letter starting from the threshold, and I'm getting stuck there. 
I'd prefer to use startswith('AB')

Comment: join the list together and ro a regex search

Comment: @John1024 because patterns are only leading (can't be within or trailing)

Comment: Is there a maximum length of pattern you'd like to match?

Comment: @IainShelvington len(max(m, key=len))-1

Comment: @John1024 you are right... tired... will correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's define your string:

```
>>> m = ['ABA','ABB', 'ABC','BCA','BCB','BCC','ABBC', 'ABBA', 'ABBC']
```

Now, let's get a count of all leading strings of length 2 or 3:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter([s[:2] for s in m] + [s[:3] for s in m if len(s)>=3])
```

To compare with your table, here are the three most common leading strings:

```
>>> c.most_common(3)
Out[15]: [('AB', 6), ('ABB', 4), ('BC', 3)]
```

#### Update

To include all keys up to up to length `len(max(m, key=len))-1`:

```
>>> n = len(max(m, key=len))
>>> c = Counter(s[:i] for s in m for i in range(2, min(n, 1+len(s))))
```

#### Additional Test

To demonstrate that we are working correctly with longer strings, let's consider different input:

```
>>> m = ['ab', 'abc', 'abcdef']
>>> n = len(max(m, key=len))
>>> c = Counter(s[:i] for s in m for i in range(2, min(n, 1+len(s))))
>>> c.most_common()
[('ab', 3), ('abc', 2), ('abcd', 1), ('abcde', 1)]
```

Comment: I think i'll accept that answer, albeit Ian's is absolutely right too.. you guys are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
counter = collections.Counter()
min_length = 2
max_length = len(max(m, key=len))
for length in range(min_length, max_length):
    counter.update(word[:length] for word in m if len(word) >= length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `accumulate()` to generate accumulated strings and the function `islice()` to get the strings with a minimal length:

```
from itertools import accumulate, islice
from collections import Counter

m = ['ABA','ABB', 'ABC','BCA','BCB','BCC','ABBC', 'ABBA', 'ABBC']

c = Counter()
for i in map(accumulate, m):
    c.update(islice(i, 1, None)) # get strings with a minimal length of 2

print(c.most_common(3))
# [('AB', 6), ('ABB', 4), ('BC', 3)]
```